# Applying B1/B2 visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

This Christmas I'm planning to visit the Las Vegas. 
Can I apply for a B1/B2 visa with traveling purpose (without business purpose)? I've already completed a DS-160 application form and chose B1/B2 type. Is it mandatory to tell both business and pleasure plan?

Comment: The slash means it's good for both, not that you must do both.

Answer (score 3):

You should apply for a B2 visa if you are only going for pleasure. However, they will almost certainly still give you a B1/B2 visa.

Comment: "You should apply for a B-2 visa if you are only going for pleasure": If someone chooses B-1/B-2 without having a business purpose, will that hurt their application?  Should TomooMGL try to modify the "already completed DS-160 application form"?